# Java insertion sort algorithm from the back of the array

Tags: java, algorithm, insertion-sort

So I have been trying to write the insertion sort algorithm so that the values are inserted towards the back of the array rather than the front (putting the largest values towards the back rather than the smallest towards the front) and I have been having trouble seeing if I am doing it right. If someone can tell me if I have the right idea, that'd be great. Here is my code, it doesn't seem to work as I want it to:

```
public static void insertionSort(Comparable[] item, int size) {
    for (int k = size - 1; k > 0; k--)
        insertInOrder(item, k);
}

private static void insertInOrder(Comparable[] item, int m) {
    Comparable save = item[m];
    for (; m > 0 && item[m-1].compareTo(save) > 0; m--)
        item[m] = item[m - 1];
    item[m] = save;
}
```

Comment: "Indexing down", I use `for (int k = size ; 0 <= --k ; )`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. Here is a fixed version:

```
public static void insertionSort(Comparable[] item, int size) {
    // Changed to k >= 0, otherwise we would have ignored the 0th
    // element and not move it to higher positions in the array
    for (int k = size - 1; k >= 0; k--)
        insertInOrder(item, k, size);
}

// Added size as a parameter
private static void insertInOrder(Comparable[] item, int m, int size) {
    Comparable save = item[m];
    // This loop needs to count upward, because you
    // want to move large values towards the back
    for (; m + 1 < size && item[m+1].compareTo(save) < 0; m++)
        item[m] = item[m + 1];
    item[m] = save;
}
```

---

Additional notes:

- Normally we pluralize the name of an array, i.e.: `Comparable[] items`.
- Consider using generics for the `Comparable` type.
- Ask your question next time on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: ([Use Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) when you have working code - and issues with it.)

Comment: @greybeard and NayukiMinase, actually no... This question is not on-topic for [codereview.se] as the question is asking about how to write code yet unwritten, inserting the values in the back rather than front. This type of question is against the on-topic rules of Code Review.

Comment: If by _issues_ you mean _broken code_, then no, Code Review is not for _broken code_. If by issues you mean spaghetti code, then sure, that's okay